# How to use method return value?

Tags: c#

I have a class and method and I am trying to use the return value inside another class method.

```
public static class GetUser
    {               
        public static string GetCurrentUser()
        {
            FulfillmentContext db = new FulfillmentContext();
            string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserName();

            var currentUser = (from u in db.AspNetUsers
                               join ur in db.AspNetUserRoles on u.Id equals ur.UserId
                               join r in db.AspNetRoles on ur.RoleId equals r.Id
                               where u.UserName == username
                               select new { u.Id, u.UserName, r.Name }).First();

            var model = new CurrentUserViewModel
            {
                Id = currentUser.Id,
                UserName = currentUser.UserName,
                Name = currentUser.Name
            };

            return model.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I am trying to use it like this. 
`String m = GetUser.GetCurrentUser()`;
What I thought I would get is m.Id, m.UserName, m.Name. But this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does *this is not working* mean specifically? How is it *not working*?

Comment: Meaning when I type m. in visual studio the dropdown helper does not display the return values to choose as I thought which to me means I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Instead of burying information in comments, [edit] your post and add it there. It's your job to clearly and specifically describe the problem, and ours to try to help you solve it. You have to do your part first, before we can do ours.

Comment: Sounds like you would want to return a CurrentUserViewModel, and not a string.  Change your method signature to `public static CurrentUserViewModel GetCurrentUser()` instead, and let whatever calls it pull the ID, UserName, and Name out of that, as needed.

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling `model.ToString()` you are actually calling [object.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) which unless you have your own override of the `ToString()` function inside `CurrentUserViewModel` doesn't do what you are expecting.

If you insist on returning string and not `CurrentUserViewModel` from your function either

- Serialize the model to Json
- Override `ToString()`in `CurrentUserViewModel` and return a string representation of your class (not really recommend).

Note that neither will really work with dropdowns or have `m.Id, m.UserName, m.Name` usage you want.

Comment: It looks like DBro suggestion is what solved my issue. Being new to C# I didn't first understand it but after studying it for awhile I now understand. Thanks all!